# Stop running vba program when the excel file running in citrix environment

Tags: excel, vba, citrix

I have excel file which should not run in citrix environment. Is there a way to check the file is running in citrix environment or local?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way may be using the Application.OperatingSystem in vba to determin the operating system the Excel file is run. A bit tricky, but may do the job for you.